# HBase 0.92 warnings about SLF4J bindings

Tags: hadoop, hbase, slf4j

I installed `HBase 0.92` on `Hadoop 1.0.0` and it works fine in full-distributed mode, but an annoying warning keeps appearing. How can I get rid of it?

```
 .......
 hbase(main):001:0> status
 SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.

 SLF4J: Found binding in
 [jar:file:/opt/hbase-0.92.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

 SLF4J: Found binding in
 [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-1.0.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
 explanation.

 3 servers, 0 dead, 0.6667 average load

 .......
```

P.S. I did not set the `$CLASSPATH` variable in `hbase-env.sh`. I run Hadoop with `start-all.sh`, then start HBase with `start-hbase.sh`.

Answer (score 16):

I removed the `slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar` in `${hase}/lib/` then the warning never shown again. It should be due to a duplicated class loaded, both `hadoop` and `hbase` use the same `jar` in the same `jvm`.

You can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The warning emitted by SLF4J is just that, a warning. Even when multiple bindings are present, SLF4J will pick one logging framework/implementation and bind with it. The way SLF4J picks a binding is determined by the JVM and for all practical purposes should be considered random. As of version 1.6.6, SLF4J will name the framework/implementation class it is actually bound to.

Embedded components such as libraries or frameworks should not declare a dependency on any SLF4J binding but only depend on slf4j-api. When a library declares a compile-time dependency on a SLF4J binding, it imposes that binding on the end-user, thus negating SLF4J's purpose. When you come across an embedded component declaring a compile-time dependency on any SLF4J binding, please take the time to contact the authors of said component/library and kindly ask them to mend their ways.

Comment: This not an answer to the Question. OP wanted to know, how to get rid of warning

Comment: remove one of the slf4j jar from the specified paths then u dont get warning

Comment: Is there anything a user can do? 
A user often does not have the admin permission to remove a jar from the path in a server environment common in a corp.